# VS Code: select file, press delete - instead of deleting file it tries to regex-find file called 'Delete'

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code I select my file in the `Explorer` tab:

[image]

After I press `Delete` button, instead of deleting VSCode starts file search:

[image: scr 2]

If I press delete multiple times it just keeps doing its thing:

[image: scr 3]

It looks like a bug but maybe there is a secret shortcut to turn file search mode on/off that I don't know. Is there?

I'm on Ubuntu x64 with VSCode:

`Version: 1.36.0
Commit: 0f3794b38477eea13fb47fbe15a42798e6129338
Date: 2019-07-03T13:20:56.241Z
Electron: 4.2.5
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.18.0-25-generic`

---

EDIT: please ignore my terrible terrible praxis of deleting spec files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update:

Microsoft fixed it in last update

#### Original answer:

This is a known issue from last patch, it's going to be fixed in the next update.

Check this: 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76514

Workaround: 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76514#issuecomment-508841597